# Dealing with a common functionality

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

I am making a product management system with Category, Brand and Product entities by using Entity framework code-first. While performing CRUD operation on any of the model, there is a common requirement of upload and removal of image.

Right now, I have inserted the code directly into my category controller. Now, when developing the CRUD functionality for Brands, I realized that i need to copy the same upload and removal code in my Brand controller as well. This will work fine but it will just duplicate the code in Brand and Product controller.

How can i make sure that i write the code once and then use it wherever required. Following is the code, i am talking about from Category Controller :

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase fileData)
    {
        if (fileData != null && fileData.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            //var fileName = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/" + Path.GetFileName(fileData.FileName));
            int pictureCount = 800000;
            pictureCount += db.Pictures.Count();
            string extension = Path.GetExtension(fileData.FileName);
            string renamedImage = Server.MapPath("~/Content/Images/Categories/cat" + pictureCount + extension);
            fileData.SaveAs(renamedImage);
            return Json("/Content/Images/Categories/" + Path.GetFileName(renamedImage));
        }
        return Json(false);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Remove(string fileName)
    {
        string completFileName = Server.MapPath("~" + fileName);
        System.IO.File.Delete(completFileName);
        return Json(true);
    }
```

Comment: What will change in your uploads for Brand and Product? pictureCount? Save path? Return value? Anything else?

Comment: well the directory will change and so will will the renaming...like for brands it will be prefixed with brand and saved in a directory brand. Picture count will work like the same way. And it will return the same usual filename

Comment: Does the common code have to access the db? I saw db.Pictures.Count() in there too.

Comment: ya....they will need to so as to rename the file. I am renaming the file on pictures count in database

Comment: Should i create a static class name commonMethods and add static methods like upload and remove to it ?

Comment: To be perfectly honest, this doesn't look like a lot of code where you would get a big return form DRYing it out. You also have quite a few variants, plus db access. For now, I would keep the upload / offload separate for the different entity types. But you may get a better answer from someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to do this is to use an [ActionFilterAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.aspx) which you can use to decorate the controller method.  You will override the [OnResultExecuting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.actionfilterattribute.onresultexecuting.aspx) method with the code you've posted, and then change your action method's signature to something like that following:

```
[UploadFile]
public ActionResult Upload(string file)
{
 ....
}

[RemoveFile]
public ActionResult Remove(string file)
{
 ....
}
```